# Methodology Approach - json string/output

Tags: javascript, php, json, bash

Hope this question is up to par for SO. I've never posted before but looking for some info in regards to approaching a task I have been assigned.

I have a page with Form information, some simple fields that I've got going.

The page outputs a json string of the form fields and writes them to a text file.

What I need to do is use the key: values to fill in a bash script to output to a hotfolder for ingestion into the production environment.

The "addmore" array needs to determine the number of filename fields produced. I should add that this is dynamic, the "addmore" array may contain 1 entry, or up to technically an unlimited number. This number will fluctuate, though.

JSON Output:

`{"formatcode":"JFM","serialnumber":"555","callletters":"555","rotator":"555","addmore":["555","444","333",""]}`

How can I use the key : value pairs to output this into a file like below:

```
{"type":"sequential","items":[
  {"filename": "/assets/$formatcode/$serialnumber/$addmore1", "description":"First item"},
  {"filename": "/assets/$formatcode/$serialnumber/$addmore2", "description": "Second item"},
  {"filename": "/assets/$formatcode/$serialnumber/$addmore3", "description": "Third item"}
]}
```

Comment: Is the description dynamic and necessary? Not sure how you would produce that without a map of 1: "First" all the way up to some maximum number of possible inputs. "item 1", "item 2" would be much simpler

Comment: Good point - no the description is not important. It is not dynamic and can remain anything.

Comment: `addmore` is an array, wich value do you want to use? How do you know that you want to generate exactly 3 rows? Imo the best way is to not look for a general solution here, but to write a little function that takes the object and returns this output.

Comment: You are right - i edited to reflect better what I am needing to do. I think Rob got me on the right track below but editing the post to make it more clear for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick, I'm using ES6 string templates to create the dynamic filename and description. The resulting object should have `addmore.length` `items`, so we reduce based on `data.addmore`, creating the basic object as our starting point (`{ type: "sequential", items: [] }`) and pushing the dynamic strings into `output.items` on each iteration.

```
const data = {
    "formatcode":"JFM",
    "serialnumber":"555",
    "callletters":"555",
    "rotator":"555",
    "addmore":[
        "555",
        "444",
        "333",
    ]
};

const desiredOutput = data.addmore.reduce((p, c, index) => {
    p.items.push({
        filename: `/assets/${data.formatcode}/${data.serialnumber}/${c}`,
        description: `Item ${index + 1}`
    });
    return p;
}, {
    type: "sequential",
    items: []
});

console.log(desiredOutput);
```

If you don't have ES6 available, you can turn the arrow function into a regular function and use the `+` concat operator instead of string templates.

Comment: This looks quite close to what I am needing - I will test in a bit and get back to you but this looks perfect and I believe I understand exactly what you are doing here.

Comment: why do you use reduce? Ain't map simpler? `var desiredOutput = { type: "sequential", items: data.addmore.map((more, index) => ({ ... })) }`

Comment: @Thomas I use `reduce` because I'm reducing one form to another and I feel it is more idiomatic. Your `map` approach is equally fine, they are likely identical in terms of performance. As for "simplicity", I think that really depends on the developer's definition of "simple"; I wouldn't define either solution as "complex".